# SAP UI5 - How to pass values for a controller?

Tags: parameter-passing, sapui5

I want to pass values from a view to controller on button press.In view am passing productJson which is an object.But i am unable to retrieve that value in controller.Please help.

View js:

```
 new sap.m.Button({
         text: "Add to Cart",
         press:[oController.addtoCartBtnPress,oController,productJson],
        })
```

Controller js:

```
 addtoCartBtnPress:function(e,oView,productJson)
      {
      }
```

Result:

```
oView and productJson values are returned as undefined.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data should be first value in the press array. Per the sdk [docs](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Button.html#event%3apress) for sap.m.Button:

> press : fnListenerFunction or [fnListenerFunction, oListenerObject] or
>   [oData, fnListenerFunction, oListenerObject]

The listener function should then have 2 arguments: 1-the event; and 2- the data.

```
onPressFn: function(evt, data) { ... }
```

To get the view, just use:

```
var view = this.getView();
```

- "this" will be equal to whatever you pass as the third value in the press array, and should usually be the controller in order to match the behaviour of xml/html views.

And an alternative to passing the data in the press call would be to use the view-model binding, especially if you are already using that model binding elsewhere in the view. But it depends how many products you have and other factors so I won't assume it will be ideal for your case.

```
//in the view
var productModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(productJson);
view.setModel(productModel, "product");

//in the controller:
var data = view.getModel("product").getData();
```

Comment: Thanks.I figured out this and it worked.Thanks anyway.Now I want pass values between two controllers.How to do that?

Comment: 1. Get controller reference with sap.ui.getCore().byId("idOfDesiredView").getController(); precondition: you have to give your JS/HTML/XMLView a unique id when creating. 2. Attach the desired data to the navigation between the controllers. 3. Store controller references globally